# Populating ListBox More Quickly

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Is there a way to make populating `ListBox` fast, because the UI is freezing on form load upon populating the `ListBox`?

This is my form load code:

```vb
Dim abc As String = itemCount()
Dim output = Account_Get(a)
For Each s In output
    ListBox1.Items.Add(s)
    count1 += 1
    If count1 = abc Then
        ListBox1.Visible = True
    End If
Next
```

This is the query in module:

```vb
Public Function Account_Get(ByVal chk As String) As List(Of String)
    Dim result = New List(Of String)()

    Try
        cn.Open()
        sql = "select column_name as str from table where status = 'New' order by rand()"
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, cn)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While dr.Read
            result.Add(dr("str").ToString())

        End While
        Return result

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgErr(ex.Message, "Error Encounter")
        Return Nothing
    Finally
        cn.Close()
    End Try

End Function
```

this is working fine. but the fact that it loads too many datas. the ui is freezing on load. hoping someone could help me with this. thanks!

Comment: For future reference, please look at the preview of your question before submitting and don't submit if the question is a mess.

Comment: Create a `DataTable`, call its `Load` method and pass the data reader to load the query result set into the `DataTable`. Set the `DisplayMember` of the `ListBox` to the name of the column you want to display, then assign the `DataTable` to the `DataSource` property.

Comment: @jmcilhinney why you don't answer instead of a comment ?

Comment: @DanielE., because, in my opinion, what I posted is not complete enough to be an answer. The comment says what should be done but doesn't actually do it, whereas an answer should do it. I didn't post such an answer because I want the OP to engage their brain and write the code for themselves.  They can then answer their own question based on that code.

Comment: Don't do the work on the UI thread, start a new one, create a task etc... There are many improvements that could be made and is off topic here, one, if the call to `Account_Get` returns nothing then the caller will bomb; `For Each s In output` specifically this line because it's nothing...

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. 
You can find this setting in 
Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults.
This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are incrementing count1 I assume it is some sort of number. However, you are then comparing it to a string in the If statement. Please use Option Strict.

Changed the Function to return an Array of String. Took the random sort form the sql statement and moved it to a little linq at the end or the function.

You could add a Stopwatch to the data retrieval and the display sections to see where your bottleneck is. BeginUpdate and EndUpdate on the listbox prevents repainting on every addition.

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim output = Account_Get()
    ListBox2.BeginUpdate()
    ListBox2.Items.AddRange(output)
    ListBox2.EndUpdate()
End Sub

Private Rand As New Random

Public Function Account_Get() As String()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim result As String()
    Using cn As New MySqlConnection("Your connection string")
        Dim Sql = "select column_name as str from table where status = 'New'" 'order by rand()"
        Using cmd = New MySqlCommand(Sql, cn)
            Try
                cn.Open()
                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error Encounter")
                Return Nothing
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
    result = (From dRow In dt.AsEnumerable()
              Let field = dRow("str").ToString
              Order By Rand.Next
              Select field).ToArray
    Return result
End Function
```

Comment: why is this line Select str).ToArray giving me an error.

Comment: So sorry, I was changing a few variable names at the last minute. It should be `Select field).ToArray` I have corrected code in the answer.

Comment: BTW, I tested with a table of about 1500 records and it filled the list box and loaded the form in the blink of an eye. Only my test was on SQL Server and a local db.

Comment: i tried your code and it loads faster now but still the ui freeze still occurs. maybe because i'm loading almost a million record. and fyi why i'm loading such big data is because ill be using it for a raffle draw. thanks again!

Comment: Wow! How can a user possibly interact with a ListBox with a million records. You must have a computer with lots of RAM.

Comment: btw. is it possible to run this on background worker ? so there will be no ui freeze ?

Comment: The Function should be able to run in background since it doesn't touch the UI directly. I have not experimented very much with Threads so, you probably know more about them than I do. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The query you are using contains a random order. Ordering records randomly can be a huge performance issue within MySQL as it has to go through all records in the table and then sort them randomly. The more records in the table, the bigger the performance penalty. There is also no limitation on the number of records in your query. So if there are thousands of items in your table the listbox will also be thousands of items in size, which could also take a long time.

If you really require the random ordering you could do something about it in your code. I'm now assuming here that you are: 1) using identifiers in your table, 2) you actually wish to limit the number of items in your listbox and not display all of them.

1. Get a grasp of the total number of records in the table by a query
2. Pick a random number from the range of items in your table
3. Fetch the nearest record

Hope this helps you to get going to find a solution

Comment: i know how to limit. i needed to load all of the data that's why i didnt use limit in my query. thanks by the way